# Why is these flex items not wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I have a flex item that is also a flex container `.sub-con`, problem is the flex item of `.sub-con` is refusing to wrap, even after adding : `flex-flow: row wrap`.

Can anyone fix this for me, or point out what I'm doing wrong.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sub-con {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col-one {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.col-two {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-con">
    <div class="col-one"></div>
    <div class="col-two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flex items in the nested container are sized with **percentages**.

```
.col-one{
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
}
.col-two{
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Because percentage lengths are based on the length of the parent they *have no reason to wrap*. They will always be 40% of the parent, even if the parent has a width of 1%.

If you use other units for length, such as `px` or `em`, they will wrap.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2xycyvr0/)

```css
 .container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   height: 100vh;
 }
 
 .sub-con {
   flex: 1;  /* for demo only */
   align-content: flex-start; /* for demo only */
   margin-right: 50px;
   margin-left: 50px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: #fff;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
 }
 
 .col-one {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid lightgreen;
 }
 
 .col-two {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-con">
    <div class="col-one"></div>
    <div class="col-two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```