# flex items won't wrap to next row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On desktop the layout of a 'product table' I have created works fine. I have used media queries to style the site for less than 850px screen width.

I have attempted to use a wrapper div with inline-flex to wrap child divs onto separate 'rows'.

What I want to happen is to have `<img class="brand">` on one row, the three `<div class="minmaxtitle">` div's (and child div's) on the next row and then `<div class="apply">` on a third row (all center aligned). The only thing not working in the attached CSS is that the image and three product detail div's are staying on the same row?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.apply {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12vw;
  padding-top: 1vw;
  padding-bottom: 1vw;
  line-height: 2.5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border-radius: .25vw;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 #cfcfcf
}

.brand {
  width: 10vw;
  vertical-align: top
}

.minmaxtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1vw;
  background: mediumseagreen;
  width: 15vw;
  padding-top: .5vw;
  padding-bottom: .5vw;
  color: white
}

.minmax {
  display: inline-block
}

.min {
  width: 7.5vw;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #ebf7f0;
  padding-top: .5vw;
  padding-bottom: .5vw
}

.max {
  width: 7.5vw;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #f7ebf2;
  padding-top: .5vw;
  padding-bottom: .5vw
}

.productbox {
  padding: .2vw;
  justify-content: middle;
  align-items: middle;
  width: 15vw;
  margin: auto
}

.productwrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center
}

@media all and (min-width:0) and (max-width:850px) {
  .brand {
    width: 20vw;
    display: inline-block
  }
  .minmaxtitle {
    background: mediumseagreen;
    width: 20vw;
    padding-top: 1vw;
    color: white;
    height: 10vw;
    vertical-align: middle
  }
  .min {
    width: 20vw;
    background: #ebf7f0;
    padding-top: .5vw;
    padding-bottom: .5vw
  }
  .max {
    width: 20vw;
    background: #f7ebf2;
    padding-top: .5vw;
    padding-bottom: .5vw
  }
  .productbox {
    justify-content: middle;
    align-items: middle;
    width: 20vw
  }
  .productwrap {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center
  }
  .apply {
    margin-top: 2vw;
    margin-bottom: 2vw;
    height: 12vw;
    line-height: 12vw;
    width: 45vw;
    align-items: left
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="productwrap">
  <div class="productbox">
    <img class="brand" alt="brand" src="http://via.placeholder.com/190x120.png">
  </div>
  <div class="productbox">
    <div class="minmaxtitle">
      <p>Detail</p>
    </div>
    <div class="minmax">
      <div class="min">From
        <br>1</div>
      <div class="max">To
        <br>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productbox">
    <div class="minmaxtitle">
      <p>Detail</p>
    </div>
    <div class="minmax">
      <div class="min">From
        <br>1</div>
      <div class="max">To
        <br>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productbox">
    <div class="minmaxtitle">
      <p>Detail</p>
    </div>
    <div class="minmax">
      <div class="min">From
        <br>1</div>
      <div class="max">To
        <br>2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productbox">
    <a class="apply" target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the source of the problem:

```
.productbox {
    justify-content: middle;
    align-items: middle;
    width: 20vw
}
```

First off, `middle` is not a valid value for flex alignment properties. Use `center` instead. But that's not what is causing the problem.

When you tell a flex item to be `width: 20vw`, it becomes 20% of the viewport width. So the item will expand and shrink to keep that 20% size. If the viewport is as narrow as 5px, the item will shrink to 20% of that, and has no reason to wrap (unless there is enough content in the item to force a minimum size).

Consider using a different unit of length, such as `px` or `em` ([but not `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46130202/3597276)).